# How to make a NSDictionary String value like a [NSNull null]

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

So I am creating a NSDictionary that is going to be passed across to another class as a paramater and then used in that class however it needs to be used.

There is one issue however, The NSDictionary has 18 values.. in this particular case only 3 are possibly used which I have got working fine, Although if in the case one of the three values is not used I would like to know how to make it look like the other entried I have in the NSdictionary [NSNull null]... Below is the code I am referring too.. I am just not sure what to do in this instance as I am fairly new to NSDictionary.. (have not used them very often).

// dont pay attention to the key id's as I have modified them for security purposed.

```
// Keys for sendSeriesDictionary
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Code", @"MID", @"MD",   
    @"SID",@"SMID",@"Yt",@"KID",@"KBID",@"K",@"CID",@"C",@"LT",
        @"Kep",@"KG",@"CD",@"LID",@"IHG",@"LID", nil];


// Objects for keys that are for sendSeriesDictionary
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNull null], MIDString, MDString,
    SIDString, [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null],
    [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null],
    [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], nil];

// Add keys and objects to NSDictionary
NSDictionary *sendSeriesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
    forKeys:keys];
```

so for instance say if SIDString was empty, how could I replace that with or fill it with a value so it would act like the other [NSNull null] values...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `NSMutableDictionary` if you want to edit the dictionary after it is created - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Then you can use `setObject:forKey:` to set whichever key's value to `[NSNull null]`.